# how to create pdf file and save data to database from user input in php

Tags: php, pdf

i have a form that can be filled by user and having the fields, name, address, mobile number,total marks of math, science etc. when i click on submit form i should have to generate a pdf file with those user input details and save it to databse

example

```
Personal Information
Name :**xyz**(Input filed)

E-mail :**xyz@gmail.com**(Input filed)

Address : **xyz address**(Input filed)

City :**xyz**(Input filed)


 **Results**

Maths: 50 marks(Input filed)

English: 56 marks(Input filed)

French: 65 marks(Input filed)
```

Comment: Why u want to save PDF file into DB? what actually is your requirement? If you save PDF in DB, you DB will be overloaded

Comment: ok tell me the simple method, it is not necessary to load that data in database, but my primary task is to generate a pdf file from user input  values with labels.

Comment: i don't want to save pdf in DB. i want to generate pdf file and save those user input data in database, in simple terms i want to generate invoice, or user input data in padf

Comment: have u found the solution? if yes, then approve answer which ever applicable. Thnx..happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Cool.. Then You can use DOMPDF

[DOM PDF Example](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php#dom_form_fieldset.html,html)

Here is the example to generate dom. You need to include this project for php and then you can check out different examples, you'l' you solution in these examples.

Let me know if need some more help.

[DOM GITHUB](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, saving a whole PDF to a database is not an effective use of resources.  You might considering saving the textual data into the database, and then having a separate script generate the PDF for you by querying data from the database.  I have had good luck with [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) for this purpose.